# How to delete blank lines from multiple files in a directory

Tags: batch-file

I need to replace blank lines from multiple files in a directory. I can do it for a single file, but I am not able to do it for multiple files in a folder.

This is the code that works for a single file

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (input.txt) do echo %%A >> output.txt
```

Please help me with this as I am absolutely new to batch programing

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting tha line of code, I was looking for just that and in a bit of a hurry to reason it out by myself :)

To use it for a series of files, yo can do the following: (you can copy the whole code into a single batch file)

```
:: Say you have several files named Input1.txt, Input2.txt, Input3.txt, etc 
:: this will call a subroutine within the same batch file, called :Strip
:: using each file as parameter:

for %%A in ("input*.txt") do call :Strip %%A
Goto End

:Strip
:: The subroutine starts here
:: First we take the name of the input file and use it to generate
:: the name of an output file, Input1.txt would output to output_(Input1).txt, etc
For %%x in (%*) do set OutF=output_(%%~nx).txt

:: I now erase the output file it it already exists, so if you run this twice
:: it won't duplicate output
del %OutF%

:: Now comes the line you already supplied
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%B in (%*) do echo %%B >> %OutF%

:: and now we return from the subroutine
Goto :EOF

:End
```