# remove blank lines from multiple files within a specific directory

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I would like to use a batch file to delete all blank lines in multiple files in the directory "Data".  I don't want to rename the files.

I have seen this post, but it does not help: [How to delete blank lines from multiple files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118686/how-to-delete-blank-lines-from-multiple-files-in-a-directory) for the following reasons:
* Files are renamed
* Files must be in same directory as the .bat file

If you could also explain the batch file commands, then that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to include all the explanations as comments. There are some ways of doing it without a rename/move operation, but are not as reliable as this. Anyway, at the end, files will have the same name but no empty lines.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem There are some problems with references to batch files
    rem that are called with quotes. To avoid the problems, a
    rem subroutine is used to retrieve the information of 
    rem current batch file 

    call :getBatchFileFullPath batch

    rem From the full path of the batch file, retrieve the 
    rem folder where it is stored 

    for %%a in ("%batch%") do set "folder=%%~dpa"

    rem We will use a temporary file to store the valid 
    rem lines while removing the empty ones.

    set "tempFile=%folder%\~%random%%random%%random%"

    rem For each file in the batch folder, if the file is 
    rem not the batch file itself

    for %%a in ("%folder%\*") do if /i not "%%~fa"=="%batch%" (

        rem Now %%a holds a reference to the file being processed
        rem We will use %%~fa to get the full path of file.

        rem Use findstr to read the file, and retrieve the
        rem lines that 
        rem    /v         do not match
        rem    /r         the regular expression
        rem    /c:"^$"    start of line followed by end of line
        rem and send the output to the temporary file

        findstr /v /r /c:"^$" "%%~fa" > "%tempFile%"

        rem Once we have the valid lines into the temporary 
        rem file, rename the temporary file as the input file
        move /y "%tempFile%" "%%~fa" >nul 
    )

    rem End - Leave the batch file before reaching the subroutine 
    exit /b 

rem Subrotutine used to retrieve batch file information.
rem First argument (%1) will be set to the name of a variable 
rem that will hold the full path to the current batch file.

:getBatchFileFullPath returnVar
    set "%~1=%~f0"
    goto :eof
```

The uncommented version

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :getBatchFileFullPath batch
    for %%a in ("%batch%") do set "folder=%%~dpa"
    set "tempFile=%folder%\~%random%%random%%random%"

    for %%a in ("%folder%\*") do if /i not "%%~fa"=="%batch%" (
        findstr /v /r /c:"^$" "%%~fa" > "%tempFile%"
        move /y "%tempFile%" "%%~fa" >nul 
    )
    exit /b 

:getBatchFileFullPath returnVar
    set "%~1=%~f0"
    goto :eof
```

Comment: Back to this after a long time ... I ended up copying the .bat file to the same directory as the files with the empty lines - however, how I would modify this to have the .bat file outside of that directory.. eg directory structure

Parent: contains .bat file
Parent\Data: contains files with empty lines

Comment: @user1420372, change the line that assigns the folder to process `for %%a in ("%batch%") do set "folder=%%~dpa\Data"`